# How to update zeros with the first non-zero value from a following row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I UPDATE the zeros with the next non-zero values in col2?

For eg - I need the first 3 rows in col2 to be updated with the value 2. Similarly, I need the next next two values after 2 to be updated with 3 (for RN 5,6)

Basically, after every trailing zeros, if there is a non-zero, it should be updated in the above trailing zeros. 
How can I do this using `loops` and `procedures`?

[image]

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I have updated the caption. MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Using a loop would certainly not be a good solution, you'll soon see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple query for this, you can just achieve this by using `OUTER APPLY`

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(rn INT IDENTITY(1,1), col1 VARCHAR(50), col2 INT, col3 DATE)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES 
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 2, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2014-02-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2013-02-01'),
('ABC', 3, '2013-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 0, '2017-01-01'),
('ABC', 7, '2017-01-01')


UPDATE t SET t.col2 = t2.col2
FROM #tmp t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 col2 FROM #tmp WHERE rn >= t.rn AND col2 > 0) t2
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
rn  col1    col2    col3
1   ABC     2       2017-01-01
2   ABC     2       2017-01-01
3   ABC     2       2017-01-01
4   ABC     2       2017-01-01
5   ABC     3       2014-02-01
6   ABC     3       2013-02-01
7   ABC     3       2013-01-01
8   ABC     7       2017-01-01
9   ABC     7       2017-01-01
10  ABC     7       2017-01-01
11  ABC     7       2017-01-01
12  ABC     7       2017-01-01
```

Comment: I must have had a brainfart missing this most elegant way of doing this :). This seems like the most preferable way.

Comment: Hi,
Could you please explain me the approach ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    RN INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    COL1 VARCHAR(20),
    COL2 INT,
    COL3 DATE,
    COL2_NEW INT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @T(COL1,COL2,COL3)
VALUES('ABC',0,'1/1/2017'),
('ABC',0,'01/01/2017'),
('ABC',0,'01/01/2017'),
('ABC',2,'01/01/2017'),
('ABC',0,'01/01/2017'),
('ABC',0,'01/01/2017'),
('ABC',3,'01/01/2014'),
('ABC',0,'01/01/2017')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.RN ORDER BY T1.RN,T2.RN),
        T1.RN,
        T2RN = T2.RN,
        T2.COL2
        FROM @T T1
            INNER JOIN @T t2
                ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1    
                    AND T1.COL2 = 0
                    AND T2.COL2 > 0
                    AND T1.RN < T2.RN
)
UPDATE @T
    SET 
        COL2_NEW = CTE.COL2
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN @T T
            ON T.RN = CTE.RN
        WHERE CTE.SeqNo = 1

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T
```

Comment: T1,T2 is the alias name for table T? I have confusion regarding the names. 
Also, SeqNo in CTE is the column for CTE ?

Comment: SeqNo is a virtual column and T1 and T2 are just alias names, you can change them as you wish

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `RN` is the column by which we determine column orders:

```
UPDATE t
SET col2 = t2.col2
FROM
    table t
        inner join
    table t2
        on
            t.rn < t2.rn and
            t2.col2 != 0
        left join
   table t_anti
       on
           t.rn < t_anti.rn and
           t_anti.rn < t2.rn and
           t_anti.col2 != 0
where
    t.col2 = 0 and
    t_anti.rn is null
```

Basically, we join the table to itself based on finding a later row with a non-zero value. We then perform a further join that tries to locate a "better" match for the later row. Only if that join fails (the final `null` check in the `where` clause) do we know that we've located the best match in `t2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick script to show the concept. For each row, find the next RN where the value is non-zero, then update the value to the value for that RN.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(RN INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
INSERT INTO #tt(val)VALUES(0),(0),(0),(2),(0),(0),(3),(0);
SELECT * FROM #tt;

UPDATE
    #tt
SET
    val=ISNULL((SELECT val FROM #tt AS r WHERE r.RN=mrn.RN),0)
FROM
    #tt AS o
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            RN=MIN(RN)
        FROM
            #tt AS i
        WHERE
            i.val<>0 AND i.RN>=o.RN
    ) AS mrn;

SELECT * FROM #tt;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```